# aarch64; Load-Acquire Exclusive vs Load Exclusive

Tags: arm, locking, arm64

What is the difference between `LDAXR` & `LDXR` instructions out of AArch64 instruction set?

From reference manual they looks totally the same (with exception of 'acquire' word):

**LDAXR** - Load-Acquire Exclusive Register: loads word from memory addressed by base to Wt. Records the physical address as an exclusive access.

**LDXR** - Load Exclusive Register: loads a word from memory addressed by base to Wt. Records the physical address as an exclusive access.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a reference to your 'reference manual', since I see something different in version D of the ARMv8 ARM.

Comment: that's out of "ARMv8 Instruction Set Overview"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simplest form, `LDAEX` == `LDXR` +`DMB_SY`.

This is the description which I find for LDAXR:

> **C6.2.104 LDAXR**
>
> Load-Acquire Exclusive Register derives an address from a base
>   register value, loads a 32-bit word or 64-bit doubleword from memory,
>   and writes it to a register. The memory access is atomic. The PE marks
>   the physical address being accessed as an exclusive access. This
>   exclusive access mark is checked by Store Exclusive instructions. See
>   Synchronization and semaphores on page B2-135. The instruction also
>   has memory ordering semantics as described in Load-Acquire,
>   Load-AcquirePC, and Store-Release on page B2-108. For information
>   about memory accesses see Load/Store addressing modes on page C1-157.

From section K11.3 of [DDI0487 Da](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0487/latest/arm-architecture-reference-manual-armv8-for-armv8-a-architecture-profile)

> The ARMv8 architecture adds the acquire and release semantics to
>   Load-Exclusive and Store-Exclusive instructions, which allows them to
>   gain ordering acquire and/or release semantics. The Load-Exclusive
>   instruction can be specified to have acquire semantics, and the
>   Store-Exclusive instruction can be specified to have release
>   semantics. These can be arbitrarily combined to allow the atomic
>   update created by a successful Load-Exclusive and Store-Exclusive pair
>   to have any of:
>
> - No Ordering semantics (using LDREX and STREX).
> - Acquire only semantics (using LDAEX and STREX).
> - Release only semantics (using LDREX and STLEX).
> - Sequentially consistent semantics (using LDAEX and STLEX).

Also (B2.3.5),

> The basic principle of a Load-Acquire instruction is to introduce
>   order between the memory access generated by the Load-Acquire
>   instruction and the memory accesses appearing in program order after
>   the Load-Acquire instruction, such that the memory access generated by
>   the Load-Acquire instruction is Observed-by each PE, to the extent
>   that that PE is required to observe the access coherently, before any
>   of the memory accesses appearing in program order after the
>   Load-Acquire instruction are Observed-by that PE, to the extent that
>   the PE is required to observe the accesses coherently.

Comment: Thanks, I searched by an instruction mnemonic and missed that part.

Comment: So just to summarise, that's only about memory ordering and simply speaking `LDAEX` == `LDXR + DMB_SY`

Comment: Note that the internal implementation does *not* have to include a barrier for *everything* like `DMB_SY`.  A high-performance implementation may only make sure it happens after any preceding release-stores, but allow reordering with previous plain stores.  That's all that's needed to make the operation itself `seq_cst`.  (This makes it possible for seq_cst on AArch64 to be significantly less expensive than on other machines, if you avoid doing a seq_cst load right after a seq_cst store or RMW.)